# Adobe Air Flex appending and saving to XML file

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, append

I'm trying to append data to an XML file using an Adobe Air app and SAVE it.

This method puts the data where I want it but it doesn't save the data;

```
reminder.insertChildBefore(xmlArray[0],             
 <item>
  <event>{txtEvent.text}</event>
  <date>{dateFormatter.format(dfDate.selectedDate)}</date>
  <dateb>{dfDate.selectedDate.toDateString()}</dateb>       
  <time>{formattedtime}</time>
 </item>);
```

The method below places it outside/below the `<reminder> </reminder>` tag of the XML, it simply adds it to the end of the file. This method saves the data.

```
var outputString:String;
outputString =

"\n"+
<item>
<event>{txtEvent.text}</event>
<date>{dateFormatter.format(dfDate.selectedDate)}</date>
<dateb>{dfDate.selectedDate.toDateString()}</dateb>     
<time>{formattedtime}</time>
</item>;

outputString = outputString.replace(/\n/g, File.lineEnding);
stream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
stream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
stream.close();
```

This option would be okay but I need to get it to delete the last line from the XML and then write a new last line. I'm probably better off using this option as I could reuse the code later in the program.

Any advice on how to get either of these methods to work correctly would be very much appreciated.

---

The idea is to add to the XML data below, the first method inserts the data correctly but doesn't save it, the second method appends it so its below the `</reminder>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<reminder>
 <item>
    <event>Christmas Day</event>
    <date>2012/12/25</date>
    <dateb>Tue Dec 25 2012</dateb>
    <time>08:00 AM</time>
  </item>
</reminder>
```

Answer (score 0):

`reminder.insertLineBefore()` actually returns the updated object, just use what's returned when writing/saving.

More info here: [`XML.insertChildBefore()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#insertChildBefore%28%29)

Comment: Well if the only problem is that it adds to the end of the file, change the line `stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);` to `stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);` then right before you call `stream.close();`, add `stream.truncate();`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I removed the <reminder>tag</reminder> problem seems to be solved

Comment: Nope, I need to use the first method otherwise I'll never get a remove item button working. I need to know how to get the first method to save the changes made to the XML file.